# How to know what to import using NPM, esp jQuery-plugins

Tags: jquery, npm-package

I'm trying to find out *what* to import if I add a (jquery-plugin) to my NodeJS with NPM.
For instance, I try to get
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-caret-plugin?activeTab=readme
to work. I've added it with NPM, no problem. But how to I know wat import-command to use?
I've tried import { caret } from 'jquery-caret-plugin' but that does not work, although
import { number } from 'jquery-number' does?

thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Turned out, the package did not have a main-parameter in the package.json.
If I added the package-path, it works:

```
import { caret } from 'jquery-caret-plugin/dist/jquery.caret.min.js'
```

:-)